# Laravel eloquent Query Reuse extra condition

Tags: laravel, eloquent, code-reuse

I have a query which gives me list of total counts of different items, as:

```
$data = DB::table($Table1)
           ->join($table2,$Table1.'.id','=',$Table2.'.device_key')
                ->where($Table1.'.created_at', '>', $value)
                ->select('item', DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
                ->groupBy('item')
                ->lists('total', 'item');
```

now i want to fetch same data with extra condition as >where($Table1.'.status', '=', 'SUCCESS') .

how do i do that ??

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you'll get away with anything nice than this.

```
$query = DB::table($Table1)
           ->join($table2,$Table1.'.id','=',$Table2.'.device_key')
                ->where($Table1.'.created_at', '>', $value)
                ->select('item', DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
                ->groupBy('item');

$data1 = $query->lists('total', 'rem');
$data2 = $query->where($Table1 . '.status', '=', 'SUCCESS')->lists('total, 'rem');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use clone to copy the query object for modifications.

```
$query = DB::table()->where();

$clonedQuery = clone $query;
$clonedQuery->where(..);
```

Comment: do i keep select and lists also part of 'query' as these will return a list of item and count so status column is not selected. will cloning this query and adding where work?